# How to get React to resolve index.ts as root of folder?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Just started a new React project and I'm wondering how I can get my project to resolve the index.js file as the folder being imported in another component.

Expected:
No error

```js
// src/pages/router.tsx
import HomePage from './home-page`

export const Router: FC = () => {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/">
        <HomePage />
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  )
}
```

```js
// src/pages/home-page/home-page.tsx/index.ts
export { HomePage as default } from './home-page'
```

Actual:
Cannot find module './home-page' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)

The `index.ts` doesn't show up as a possible import either.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your screenshot is cutoff, but that's not where the file is:

[image]

That image shows your `index.ts` is actually in `home-page/home-pa...` (which is truncated in your screenshot.

You either need to move the `.ts` files to the correct directory, or change you import to:

```
import HomePage from './home-page/home-page-or-whereever-this-is'
```

Comment: Wow - you are a wizard and gentleman. Thank you.